# Mongoose NodeJS macOS Big Sur MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, macos-big-sur

I'm using brew mongodb-community on macOS Big Sur and can connect to mongo shell with mongosh. But when I try to run NodeJS and Mongoose app I get `MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`. Why can I connect to mongodb with mongo shell but not NodeJS and Mongoose?

Edit: Sample code from my NodeJS Mongoose code

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Comment: Guess in the wild, you are mixing IPv4 & IPv6. How do you try to connection from node to mongodb?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My solution was to use `127.0.0.1` and NOT `localhost`. For some reason Mongoose can read `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb` and NOT `mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb`

Comment: If the local node supports IPv6 `localhost` will resolve to `::1`, not `127.0.0.1`, so if you have not enabled IPv6 in the mongod config and instructed it to listen on `::1` there will be nothing there to connect to.

Comment: thankyou my lord and savior

Answer (score 0):

Your MongoDB Server is not up, Try brew services start mongodb-community@6.0.

if not started kindly follow below commands.

Step-1:  install brew from [download brew](https://brew.sh)

"**At the end brew shows to add path in your terminal**"(which many people forget to add)

For reference, The below commands will appear in your terminal:
==> Next steps:

- Run these three commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:

echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/xxxx/.zprofile

echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/xxxxx/.zprofile

eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

---

Step-2 : install MongoDB:

brew install mongodb-community@6.0

Step-3 : Start MongoDB Server:

brew services start mongodb-community@6.0

Please refer [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#std-label-osx-prereq)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).